# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'. error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update

I need to find matching id from two tables (client & activity), and update the data from (clientid) column in table client to the same column (id) the other table (activity):

```
update activity
set a.clientid = r.clientid 
where (select r.clientid, r.id 
       from request r 
       where exists(select a.activityid from activity a where (a.id = r.id))
```

It throws an exception

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Comment: The `where exists()` needs to be `where exists() = 1` - you need to compare this `exists` expression to a `BIT` value (0 or 1)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: A `)` is missing. If that's a post composition typo & not what your ran--have you checked against the grammar & limitations in the manual? Always read the manual re functionality you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an update with `join`.  In SQL Server, this looks like:

```
update a
    set clientid = r.clientid 
from activity a join
     request r
     on a.id = r.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure without sample data but it looks like you're looking for

```
UPDATE activity a
JOIN request r ON r.id = a.id
SET a.clientid = r.clientid
```